# React double values, useEffect and setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why do I have double values? I am using useEffect and the setInterval function. In the setInterval function there is a single increment or decrement and after a second there is another one. Why am I getting a double value in the results? How to change it?

```
  const demo = "1 2 3 4 5";
  let i = 0;  
  let j = demo.length;
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (i < demo.length) {
        console.log(demo.substring(0, i));
        i++;
      } else if (j > 0) {
        console.log(demo.substring(0, j));
        j--;
      }
    }, 1000);
  }, [i, j]);
```

Result:

```
1
1 
1 2
1 2 
1 2 3
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 
1 2 3
1 2 
1 2
1 
1
```

Comment: "demo" shouldn't contain spaces. It should be "12345", or an array [1, 2, 3, 4 5]. "i" and. "j" should also probably be stateful variables, take a look at the useState hook.

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting double values, you are getting the spaces in the `demo` string.

You results is

```
'1'
'1 '
'1 2'
'1 2 '
'1 2 3'
'1 2 3 '
'1 2 3 4'
'1 2 3 4 '
'1 2 3 4 5'
'1 2 3 4 '
'1 2 3 4'
'1 2 3 '
'1 2 3'
'1 2 '
'1 2'
'1 '
'1'
```

Comment: OMG thx bro, I'm an idiot